# How to flag Hardware recommendations questions?

Tags: discussion

I didn't know how to flag [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/419298/164891) and ended up choosing 'other (needs ♦ moderator attention)' and leaving a note as to why I think it should be closed.

This turns out to be the wrong way to go - so which reason would be correct in this case?

P.S I wanted to choose 'This is not about Ubuntu...', but the recommendations offered will then only guide the user to other software related sites and not hardware ones - should hardware sites maybe be included in this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags are used for issues that need specific moderator attention.

They are used sometimes to flag posts that should be handled by users with more reputation and privileges, in this case the privilege of voting to close. Flagging should not be use to circumvent that, if it can be handled by users with more reputation then it should, that is why you flag was possibly rejected with *Declined: flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*.

I think from all possible action, what you did was the best one. But not really necessary to be flagging everything. Spend that time getting some more reputation and you will be able to vote like other users do.

Comment: Flagging for a diamond is the *only* way to flag for a custom off-topic reason - Are you saying users aren't supposed to flag custom-off-topic questions at all?

Comment: @FEichinger No, I am saying that we need to add another reason for close voting since this is BS like this. Flags should not really be used as close votes, if we have a base of users that can work by themselves why, oh God why, do you need to bother mods for that?

Comment: At times you use flagging to refer to moderator flagging (that will alert a moderator as oppose to a member with privileges) in your post, right? (The way it is currently stated is somewhat confusing)

Comment: No, one thing is you, having earned the privilege to issue close votes, selecting off-topic and writing something like "Hardware recommendations and shopping advise posts are off-topic for the site", another thing is you flagging the post and saying that the ports is off-topic for the site because of the same reason. The first one is the default on the current work-flow, the second one is sort of not what flags should be used for...

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is that if I were to have enough privileges I would be able to 'create' a custom off-topic (only if needed of course), but until then I should rather leave it if I can't find the correct reason amongst the current flags?